# how to go from sql database to ajax/jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, sql, ajax, vb.net

How can I go from an SQL statement to AJAX?
I know this is a broad question so here is what I am trying to do and what I have tried.

I have using asp.net(vb) connected to the database and put the information in a dataset and datagrid.
(I don't want to use a datagrid anymore)

I know how to make my dataset into xml and json. 
After this I am stuck.

Comment: I would suggest you start learning ASP.NET (to use with VB.NET). It's the first step you need to achieve what you are trying to.

Comment: Do you know any good tutorials or examples on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a purely jQuery standpoint, if you were to just print the json out to an otherwise blank page, jQuery would be able to load that data via `$.getJSON()` or another appropriate Ajax function. Just make sure you don't print anything else to the page like any html tags.

Comment: I would want to format the layout of table using html, that isn't possible?

Comment: Well, the json is purely the data portion of it, which you could load and then print and format as you'd like with jQuery. The page I'm suggesting is an entirely separate page from where your Javascript code is, which jQuery will make an Ajax call to to load the json data.

Comment: what if the json string is dependent on a search the person did.

Comment: jQuery Ajax calls let you send GET or POST parameters as well, so your codebehind to generate the json can work dependent upon those passed values, then simply print nothing but json, which jQuery will retrieve as the response data, and you can then manipulate and use in your page.